# Lunatic Loves this Sunny Sequence......Find the Missing info

Tags: knowledge

Complete this Sunny Sequence,

Based on the information given below:

[image: sunny sequence]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution

> The missing letters are J, E and M

And the missing numbers are:

> 79, 1, 0

Because

> We then have the eight planets in the Solar system, from the furthest to the closest to the Sun: **N**eptun, **U**ranus, **S**aturn, **J**upiter, **M**ars, **E**arth, **V**enus and **M**ercury, each with the number of its (known) moons.

Comment: That’s right...

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:

> N 14
>
> U 27
>
> S 62
>
> J 79
>
> M 2
>
> E 1
>
> V 0
>
> M 0

Where

> each letter is the initial of a planet in our solar system and the number is its number of moons.

Comment: Ah, beaten to it! Well done @Evargalo

Comment: You were pretty close..